# Add prefix to control id and still have it bind MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a case where I have a page displaying an order and tabs that display the order details. The order details are quite complex and since they are the same layout, I want to use a partial view or editor template that will generate the form.

The problem is the result is multiple duplicate form input id's are generated (one for each order detail. For example, I have:

```
foreach (var orderDetail in Model.OrderDetils)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => orderDetail, "WorkOrder", orderDetail)
}
```

I've read much about this and see solutions where it is recommended to use an editortemplate, but that solution only works when you have the same form to render, but passing it different model properties so the control id's prefixes will differ...ie. [like this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209520/same-partial-view-on-one-page-how-to-handle-binding).

In my case, this won't work as the model property I am passing is always the same.

So how else can I create unique Id's in the partial or editor template that will also bind.

I know instead of:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WOHdr.Attribute1)
```

I could do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WOHdr.Attribute1, new { id = Model.Id + "_Attribute1" })
```

But then it won't bind when it passes to the controller.

Thoughts?

Comment: Values in action are accessed using field names, not id's.

Comment: @YD1m Thanks, that is good to know...so binding isn't affected if you manipulate the Id...as long as you leave the Name alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WOHdr.Attribute1, new { @id = @Model.Id + "_Attribute1" })
```

Use "@"+dynamic value. Now You will get unique Id's

In EditorFor you can use like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WOHdr.Attribute1, null, "id=" + @Model.Id + "" )
```

the id will generate like this

```
id="id_1", id="id_2" and so on..
```

Comment: Thanks, this partially works...from what I've read everywhere, you can't override the Id when using EditorFor and I tried what you proposed for EditorFor to do so, but it did not work. Overriding the Id by using TextBoxFor does work....but my issue is that I have editor templates for some of my fields...which if I have an EditorTemplate specified in the model, even though I used TextBoxFor and override the Id, the editorTemplate is still used (good), but it ignores the Id specified in the textBoxFor.

Answer (score 0):

`<input id="Checkbox1_@(test.TestId)" type="checkbox" />`

i hope upper code will help you