# Get specific html element when clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a web app i'm working on, and i have a foreach loop in the cshtml file to display a list of values in boxes
[image]

```
        
        @foreach(var obj in Model)
        {
            List<double> PN = new List<double>();
            PN.Add(obj.ComponentNumber);
            @if (obj.ComponentNumber == 3391012471)
            {
                <div class="box">

                    <div class="parent">
                            <h3 class="column inline-block-column">PN - @obj.ComponentNumber </h3>
                        <l class="circle-comp column1 inline-block-column" style="@ViewBag.check2"></l>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <p class="column">物料描述 - @obj.ComponentDescription</p> 
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" @ViewBag.check5>
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="box">

                    <div class="parent">
                        <h3 class="column inline-block-column">PN - @obj.ComponentNumber </h3>
                        <l class="circle-comp column1 inline-block-column"></l>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <p class="column">物料描述 - @obj.ComponentDescription</p>
                        <label id="knob" class="switch" >

                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="sendmsg()" checked="checked">
                            <span  class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
            }
```

My aim is that when the checkbox is clicked, I would like to get that specific box and change a value in it, but so far all I have tried did not work (I tried using 'getElementById' to get the box #div and change its innerHTML value, but that changed all the boxes value. I would like to be able to distinguish each box which was created using the @foreach loop)
I would appreciate guidance or suggestions from anyone on how to go about this.

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? You need to be a lot more specific, if you want help.

Comment: You need two things to make this work correctly. 1) you need to use `Id` values on your `div`s as the way to do selection in javascript -- rather than `box#div`; 2) AND you need to add some Razor code to make `Id` value for each `div` unique.  See the following post for some examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607172/add-prefix-to-control-id-and-still-have-it-bind-mvc-razor

Comment: Thank you very much. Your comment and the link you attached has helped me in figuring out how to go about it.